# What portions of the book are in each Hobbit movie?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, adaptation-comparison

My friend's review of *The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies*

> Well, considering that they took about 25 pages of the book and turned it into a 2 hour movie, not terrible. But it was like one long battle and no plot.

It's been some 30 years since I read the Hobbit, but I'm pretty certain she was exaggerating. Still, it made me wonder how much of the book *was* covered in each movie.

**What portions of the book does each movie cover?**

Since page numbers will vary from one edition to the next, I'm looking for either chapters (roughly speaking, since some material was added) and/or general high-level plot points.

Comment: I know that the first movie lasts until around the end of _Out of the Frying-Pan, Into the Fire_ but it should be noted that Azog was long dead in the books (he was actually slain when Thorin in the movie thought he was).

Comment: Don't loose track of the fact these Hobbit movies elaborate far beyond the book, pulling in elements from the Silmarillion, incorporating elements from LOTR, and making up a ton of other stuff... // I'd be ok with this under the theory that Bilbo wrote The Hobbit for children and left a lot out on purpose -- except that the first two movies were so poor (esp. compared to Jackson's LOTR of just one decade earlier).  I don't even know if I'm going to bother seeing the third.

Comment: @zipquincy - don't forget that Jackson is legally prohibited from using anything from the Silmarillion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first movie, An Unexpected Journey, covers chapters 1 to 6, a total of just over 81 pages in the copy I'm currently referencing.  This comprises:

- The Unexpected Party and formation of the company.
- The Trolls.
- Rivendell.
- Crossing the Misty Mountains and the Goblins.
- Gollum.
- The Eagles.

Desolation of Smaug covers chapters 7 to 12, or 82 pages.

- Beorn.
- Mirkwood and the Spiders.
- Capture by and escape from the Elves.
- Lake-town.
- Erebor and the Secret Door.
- Smaug.

The Battle of Five Armies covers chapters 13 to 19, a further 50 pages.

- The Dwarves in Erebor.
- Destruction of Lake-town and Death of Smaug.
- Prelude to the Battle.
- Bilbo and the Arkenstone.
- The Battle.
- The Journey Home and the Auction.

So as far as the book is concerned, it's a fairly even divide (6/6/7), although it's notable that the page-count covered by the last movie is quite a bit shorter (although there is a lot happening in those fewer pages).

What's interesting is that in the movies, Jackson & co reversed the first two parts of the third movie/section.  What's especially interesting is that in doing so, they actually ended up restoring the order that Tolkien had originally written those chapters in.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "reversal" you mention. This is why I need *The Annotated Hobbit*!

Comment: @MattGutting - it's actually in the History of the Hobbit.

Comment: @phantom42 - as you'll notice, the Dol Guldur storyline doesn't appear here; in the book it's just an excuse to get Gandalf away from the company so that Bilbo has a chance to show his worth, and there's no detail at all about it (aside from a passing mention at the end).